# Make an 8x8 size table with `ng-repeat`

Tags: angularjs

I am following the tutorial for AngularJS [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) and at the end, there is a small challenge to make an 8x8 table with an additional `ng-repeat`.

[image]

I've come up with the brute force solution, but is very clumsy. How would I improve on this solution and get to the best approach?

```
    <table>
      <tr><th ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">{{i}}</th></tr>
      <tr><th ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">{{i}}</th></tr>
      <tr><th ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">{{i}}</th></tr>
      <tr><th ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">{{i}}</th></tr>
      <tr><th ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">{{i}}</th></tr>
      <tr><th ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">{{i}}</th></tr>
      <tr><th ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">{{i}}</th></tr>
      <tr><th ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">{{i}}</th></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two ng-repeats, one for the columns and another one for the rows:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
        <td ng-repeat="col in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">row#:{{row}} col#:{{col}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and, if you want the arrays of the col/row number 1 based instead of 0 based, then create the arrays that way...

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use two loops one for creating the rows and another one for creating the cells within a row. You would something like this:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]"> <!--This is for creating Rows -->
        <td ng-repeat="j in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">({{row}}, {{col}})</td> <!--This is for creating column within row -->
    </tr>
</tbody>    
</table>
```